# Twig\Error\RuntimeError An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template

Tags: php, yii2, twig

i am using twig in my yii2 project and in my composer

```
"yiisoft/yii2-twig": "~2.0.0"
```

And i added config like

```
'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'csrfParam' => '_csrf-frontend',
        ],
        'view' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\View',
            'renderers' => [
                'twig' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\twig\ViewRenderer',
                    'cachePath' => '@runtime/Twig/cache',
                    // Array of twig options:
                    'options' => [
                        'auto_reload' => true,
                    ],
                    'globals' => [
                        'html' => ['class' => '\yii\helpers\Html'],
                    ],
                    'uses' => ['yii\bootstrap'],
                ],
                // ...
            ],
        ],
]
```

But i am getting a runtime error like

```
Twig\Error\RuntimeError
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The file or directory to be published does not exist: C:\xampp\htdocs\dobuyme/vendor/bower-asset/twig.js").
```

How can i solve this issue.Thanks in advance

Comment: Does that file exist?

Comment: try running `composer update` again, may be some installation issue so the missing files